# Looks like no data entering rows

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I'm relative noob.  When retrieving a row with my getAnimal() method it fails on "CursorIndexOutOfBoundsexception Index 0 requested with a size of 0.  I then looked at the moveToFirst() and it returns false always........

Inserting rows in the database returns incrementing indices.  The getCount() is returning incrementing amounts of rows as I run the db.insert() method. So the table appears to have columns but no data in the rows.  Am I entering the rows incorrectly or what else am I doing that is wrong?

This is DatabaseHelper Activity

```
package com.example.testdbrev2on071314;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "testdb";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_ANIMAL = "strings";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID= "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_TYPE = "type";

public String name1="Spiders";
public String type1="Black Widow";      


  DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }


// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_BIDS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ANIMAL + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY           KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TYPE + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_BIDS_TABLE);
}


// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ANIMAL);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}


// Adding new contact
public long addBid() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME,name1); 
    values.put(KEY_TYPE,type1);
    long ret= db.insert(TABLE_ANIMAL, null, values);
    db.close(); 
    return ret;
}


     String getAnimal(int id) {
         String name;
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ANIMAL, new String[] { KEY_ID,
             KEY_NAME,KEY_TYPE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
             new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
     boolean moved=cursor.moveToFirst();
     if(cursor != null) {name="Cursor OK";} 
     if(!moved){    name="Not at first";} else {name="at first";}
     return name;
 }

public int getCount() {
   String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ANIMAL;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
   int count=cursor.getCount();
   cursor.close();
   return count;
   }
```

}

The MainActivity is as follows:

```
package com.example.testdbrev2on071314;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.number);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    String  num=Integer.toString((int)db.addBid());
//  String num= db.getAnimal(0);

tv.setText(num);

}
}
```

Searched high and low and going crazy so any help would be really appreciated

Comment: Always check if cursor returned any results like this: `if (cursor.moveToFirst())` you don't need no null checks.

Comment: Are you actually using one of the ids returned by `addBid()` with the `getAnimal()` method?

Comment: #luksprog no I am not using the ids returned. Just checking the method executed. I had a problem with an apk and wrote this just to see what I am doing wrong. I am adding rows and cannot read them out. As I say, the rows are there count-wise as the count is going up as addBid()'s are executed but cursor.MoveToFirst() always returns FALSE.

Comment: @Luksprog  no I am not using the ids returned. Just checking the method executed. I had a problem with an apk and wrote this just to see what I am doing wrong. I am adding rows and cannot read them out. As I say, the rows are there count-wise as the count is going up as addBid()'s are executed but cursor.MoveToFirst() always returns FALSE. –

Comment: I was asking because I see you commented the line `String num= db.getAnimal(0);`. You are imposing a constraint on the query that you make to match the id 0, if you don't have a row with this id in the database then your cursor will be empty. For example run this: `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ANIMAL, new String[] { KEY_ID,
             KEY_NAME,KEY_TYPE }, null,
             null, null, null, null, null);` and see if the cursor is still empty(this query will retrieve all rows from the database, there is no constraint).

Comment: @Luksprog. Worked and thank you for the explanation. Many thanks - genius!